# Does the unary number system have fractions?

Tags: fractions, number-systems

Is there a way to write a fraction in [unary number system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_numeral_system)?

What I mean is to write a fraction part using a "comma" notation. Writing it just as a fraction is obvious:
$$
\frac {111}{1111}_{(1)} = \frac {3}{4}_{(10)}
$$

For other positional system's it's easy as the fraction digits are defined as a base to the power of -1, -2, -3 and so on. But for unary it doesn't work.

I know the unary number system doesn't even have zero and fractions are a step further.

But maybe there is some way to write it?

Comment: Can we make sense of something like $0.111$ in the unary system at all ? The unary system is apparently very artificial and cumbersome. It is surprising that it is accepted as a "number-system" at all.

Comment: Base k numeric system is defined as $a_nk^n + a_{n-1}k^{n-1} ... a_1k^{1} + a_0$, and numbers after decimal point continue this trend so we get $ a_{-1}k^{-1} + a_{-2}k^{-2} ...$ 

For a $k \ne 1$, you start adding fractional numbers, but for $k = 1$, even after decimal you still get $1$. So the best representation with "decimal" point is to represent it as a denominator in a fraction I guess.